DevExpress XPManyToManyAliasList in ListView
I need to edit XPManyToManyAliasList property in listview through  XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor.
I wrote a TypeConverter and it works fine in detail view for XPManyToManyAliasList if parent is a PersistentObject (object is saved in DB).
If object created but still not saved (exists in objectspace only), the TypeConverter is not called and XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor throws a NullReferenceException.
Also list view CellValueChanged event gets null value from the XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor.
I need editor for multiple selection for XPManyToManyAliasList property.
Is a way to fix XafariMultipleLookupPropertyEditor for list view to make it work correctly with objects not yet saved in the database?
I'm using Devexpress v19.2
